# Как правильно вызывать метод select из модуля selectors на windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, веб-программирование, сокет

Я написал немного кода для обработки подключений, но похоже что часть кода является платформозависимой и я не знаю как это исправить. Сам код:

```
import socket
import selectors

selector = selectors.DefaultSelector()


def server():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind(('localhost', 5000))
    server_socket.listen()

    selector.register(fileobj=server_socket, events=selectors.EVENT_READ, data=accept_connetcion)


def accept_connetcion(server_socket):
    client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
    print('Connection from', addr)

    selector.register(fileobj=client_socket, events=selectors.EVENT_READ, data=send_message)

def send_message(client_socket):
    request = client_socket.recv(4096)

    if request:
        response = 'Hello world\n'.encode()
        client_socket.send(response)
    else:
        selector.unregister(client_socket)
        client_socket.close()

    client_socket.close()


def event_loop():
    while 8599:

        events = selector.select(timeout=0)

        for key, _ in events:
            callback = key.data
            callback(key.fileobj)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server()
    event_loop()
```

В общем-то первая часть кода работает, и при подключении через netcat выводится: "Connection from ('127.0.0.1', 22310)". Но при выводе "hello world" выдаётся следующая ошибка с указанием на строку

```
events = selector.select(timeout=0)
```

OSError: [WinError 10038] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на объекте, не являющемся сокетом.
Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в конце `send_message` сокет закрывается. Причём, если из сокета данные были предварительно получены, то закрывается он без удаления из селектора, а если данные получены не были, то закрывается дважды. То есть в любом случае возникнет ошибка.

P.S. Использовать нулевой таймаут - плохая идея, это приводят к повышенной нагрузке на процессор.